# Calculating a location on a circle given an angle of rotation

Tags: rotation, trigonometry, coordinate-systems, algebra

Okay algebra and trig are not my strong suit by any means so here is what I need to do.

I have a circle which is measured in degrees from +180 to -180   (360 total)

Given the center point of the circle stays the same, Cx , Cy.
The angle varies from -180 to +180

I need to locate a point that regardless the given angle is + 3 units away that is at the 90 degree position and the 270 degree position (from the given degrees)

So like...
    Angle = 0
    Point 1 ->  x = 0, y -3
    Point 2 ->  x = 0, y + 3

And if the angle was say 90 (provided its measured Clockwise)
    Point 1 -> x = -3, y = 0
    Point 2 -> x = 3, y = 0

What I need is a forumla that will accept Angle, then tell me what my x/y should be 3 units away from the origin.

I have tried:  EDIT Updated to double precision using Java.

`double x = Cx + 3 * Math.cos((d + 90) * Math.PI / 180);'

'double y = Cy + 3 * Math.sin((d + 90) * Math.PI / 180);`

this gives me mixed results, I mean sometimes it's where I think it should be and other times its quite wrong.

```
Assuming Cx = 0.500, Cy = 0.500
Sample Data:      Result:
Deg = 0           x =  2 / y = 5
Deg = 90          x = -1 / y = 2
Deg = 125         x = -0.457 / y = 0.297
Deg = 159         x =  0.924 / y = -0.800
```

I realize I am only calculating one point at this point but do you have any suggestions on how to get the first point working?  at say 90 degrees from whatever degree I start with?

Comment: do you really want integer results when in the general case floating point will be more precise?  If so how are you doing the rounding?

Comment: most of my inputs will be a whole integer  or at the very most the only precision would be .5  so a  double result would be precise enough.   For this project.

Comment: Your formula is correct. How are you calculating you results? Using a calculator? Using a programming language? Using Excel? Because you are getting the wrong answers.

Comment: I am using java, and casting to int to find the whole number coordinates does the -180 to 180 matter with this formula?

Comment: Okay i switched to double precision, and with the same formula and now I get the following:     Deg 1 - x = 5.8,y = 4.99     Deg 92 ---- x = -2.99, y = 1.89

Comment: Updated original post to show double precision, and updated sample data.  Should I be muliplying by 3 instead of adding it since my degrees will be from -180 to + 180 ??

Comment: You multiply by 3 if you want your point to be at a distance 3units from your centre point. The cos and sin functions can take any angle positive or negative and still do the right thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104795/discussion-between-user3305347-and-gavinbrelstaff).

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = Cx + r * Math.cos( (d+90) * Math.PI / 180 );

 y = Cy + r * Math.sin( (d+90) * Math.PI / 180 );
```

Seems that this is the correct formula for what I was trying to accomplish.  This will take any value for Cx/Cy's origin add the Radius r, then calculate the degrees + 90 and convert to radians..   Once all that magic takes place, you're left with an x/y coord that is 90 degrees of where you started.